# Cassandra and Spark Thrift Server Integration

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-thriftserver

I'm trying to integrate Cassandra and Spark Thrift server. I followed the steps from [here](https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/spark-thrift-server-cassandra-example/)

I get the following error while registering the cassandara tables in beeline console.

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:23 cannot recognize input near 'USING' 'org' '.' in create table statement (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Below is the query I run

```
CREATE TABLE test_data USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra OPTIONS (keyspace 'abc', table 'def');
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I got the issue fixed. I added the cassandra connector as a aux jar in hive-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

add the cassandra connector as a aux jar in hive-site.xml